# Passing an array to DLL and testing to see if its Null

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, dll

I am trying to put some code in place to test to see if the array I'm passing to my DLL is empty or not.  I'm having some difficulty formulating the 'if' statement to check for this.

```
int[] values = null;  //1 dimensional array 
Class1.ascendingArray(values);  //Send 1 dimensional array to DLL for ascending sort method
```

DLL

```
 namespace DLLProject
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public static int[] ascendingArray(int[] values)  //Array ascending sorting method
        {
              Array.Sort(values); //Sorts array
              return values;              
        }
```

Right now the DLL code just sorts and returns the values of the array passed to it.  I want to put a check for null statement in there somewhere, but I'm having difficulty.  The DLL code also requires that you return something which is another obstacle I'm having with my array null check

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why the following would not work or have I misunderstood the question?

```
public bool IsArrayEmpty(object[] arr)
{
    return arr == null || arr.Length < 1;
}
```

With regard to ensuring something is returned, you could always treat the situation as *exception*al:

```
if (IsArrayEmpty(values)) { throw new Exception("Array is empty or null!"); }
```

Comment: Well yes, assuming that is where you want to check if the array is empty?